# Wait for a process to finish OR for the user to press a key

Tags: bash, shell-script, function, user-input

I need two ways to terminate a part of my bash script.

Either a counter reaches a predefined number, or the user manually forces the script to continue with whatever the value the counter currently has.

Specifically - I'm listing USB drives. If there is 15 of them, the function that counts them exits and the script can continue.

My code looks a bit like this:

```
scannew(){
    NEW=0
    OLD=$NEW
    while [ true ]; do
        # count the new drives
        lsblk -r > drives.new
        diff drives.old drives.new | grep disk | cut -d' ' -f 2 | sort > drives.all
        NEW=$(wc -l drives.all | cut -d' ' -f1)
        echo -en "   Detected drives: $NEW    \r"
        sleep 0.01
        if [ "$NEW" -eq "15" ]; then # exit if we reach the limit
            break
        fi
    done
}

# SOME CODE...

lsblk -r > drives.old

scannew & # start live device counter in the background
SCAN_PID=$! # remember it's PID
wait $SCAN_PID 2>/dev/null # wait until it dies
echo "It's on!"

# REST OF THE CODE...
```

I tried various stuff with the `read` command, but the result is, the script will always wait for read to exit (after pressing ENTER) and I can't make the "15 limit" condition to override that.

For example I tried using `read -t` instead of `sleep` in the `scannew()` function:

```
scannew(){
    NEW=0
    OLD=$NEW
    while [ true ]; do

        # count the new drives
        lsblk -r > drives.new
        diff drives.old drives.new | grep disk | cut -d' ' -f 2 | sort > drives.all
        NEW=$(wc -l drives.all | cut -d' ' -f1)
        echo -en "   Detected drives: $NEW    \r"
        read -t 0.01 -n 1 && break # read instead of sleep
        if [ "$NEW" -eq "15" ]; then
            break
        fi
    done
}
```

However - it seems that the function subprocess doesn't have access to stdin, and using `read -t 0.01 -n 1 < /dev/stdin && break` instead didn't work either.

How can I make this work?

Comment: I'm confused about `read -t 0.01 -n 1 || break`: Don't you want to break on user input? But I thought read returns zero on receiving input, so you should use `&&` instead.

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake when re-writing the code from memory. Of course it should be &&. Correcting.

Comment: Do you need to run the scanning loop in the background? Background processes usually get stopped if the try to read from the terminal, and you're just `wait`ing for it immediately after anyway.

Comment: You can use `read` but place it in the main script - once a key is pressed, you can send a signal to the background process, using `kill`. With `trap` you can handle the signal any way you want (I'd recommend using `USR1` or `USR2`). Since `scannew` does nothing more than scan the devices, your `trap` can just do `return 0`. AFAIK you can set up a trap from within a function so no worries there. Just make sure you define the trap at the start of `scannew`, just in case. _Reading ilkkachu's message, I think you should check if `scannew` is actually doing something when it's taking time_.

Comment: @MechaLynx you should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start by saying, you *could* just inline all the stuff you have in `scannew`, since you're `wait`ing anyway, unless you intend to scan again at some other point in your script. It's really the call to `wc` that you're concerned might take too long, which, if it does, you can just terminate it. This is a simple way to set that up using `trap` which allows you to capture signals sent to a process and set your own handler for it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# print a line just before we run our subshell, so we know when that happens
printf "Lets do something foolish...\n"

# trap SIGINT since it will be sent to the entire process group and we only
# want the subshell killed
trap "" SIGINT

# run something that takes ages to complete
BAD_IDEA=$( trap "exit 1" SIGINT; ls -laR / )

# remove the trap because we might want to actually terminate the script
# after this point
trap - SIGINT

# if the script gets here, we know only `ls` got killed
printf "Got here! Only 'ls' got killed.\n"

exit 0
```

However, if you want to retain the way you do things, with `scannew` being a function run as a background job, it takes a bit more work.

Since you want user input, the proper way to do it is to use `read`, but we still need the script to go on if `scannew` completes and not just wait for user input forever. `read` makes this a bit tricky, because `bash` waits for the current command to complete before allowing `trap`s to work on signals. The only solution to this that I know of, without refactoring the entire script, is to put `read` in a `while true` loop and give it a timeout of 1 second, using `read -t 1`. This way, it'll always take at least a second for the process to finish, but that may be acceptable in a circumstance like yours where you essentially want to run a polling daemon that lists usb devices.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

function slow_background_work {
    # condition can be anything of course
    # for testing purposes, we're just checking if the variable has anything in it
    while [[ -z $BAD_IDEA ]]
    do
        BAD_IDEA=$( ls -laR / 2>&1 | wc )
    done

    # `$$` normally gives us our own PID
    # but in a subshell, it is inherited and thus
    # gives the parent's PID
    printf "\nI'm done!\n"
    kill -s SIGUSR1 -- $$
    return 0
}

# trap SIGUSR1, which we're expecting from the background job
# once it's done with the work we gave it
trap "break" SIGUSR1

slow_background_work &

while true
do
    # rewinding the line with printf instead of the prompt string because
    # read doesn't understand backslash escapes in the prompt string
    printf "\r"
    # must check return value instead of the variable
    # because a return value of 0 always means there was
    # input of _some_ sort, including <enter> and <space>
    # otherwise, it's really tricky to test the empty variable
    # since read apparently defines it even if it doesn't get input
    read -st1 -n1 -p "prompt: " useless_variable && {
                              printf "Keypress! Quick, kill the background job w/ fire!\n"
                              # make sure we don't die as we kill our only child
                              trap "" SIGINT
                              kill -s SIGINT -- "$!"
                              trap - SIGINT
                              break
                            }
done

trap - SIGUSR1

printf "Welcome to the start of the rest of your script.\n"

exit 0
```

Of course, if what you actually want is a daemon that watches for changes in the number of usb devices or something, you should look into `systemd` which might provide something more elegant.

Comment: I had to add a `trap "break" SIGINT` in the beginning of `slow_background_process()` and move the `kill -s SIGUSR1 -- $$` inside the while loop, but it's working!

Answer (score 1):

A (somewhat) general solution for running a given command and killing it should there be input from the user, otherwise exiting. The gist is to perform the read in a somewhat-raw terminal mode looking for the "any" key, and to handle the run-program-exits case via the `SIGCHLD` signal that should be sent when the child exits (assuming no funny business from the child process). [Code and docs (and eventual tests)](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/tree/master/misc).

```
#ifdef __linux__
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#endif

#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int Flag_UserOkay;              // -U

struct termios Original_Termios;
pid_t Child_Pid;

void child_signal(int unused);
void emit_help(void);
void reset_term(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ch, status;
    char anykey;
    struct termios terminfo;

    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "h?U")) != -1) {
        switch (ch) {
        case 'U':
            Flag_UserOkay = 1;
            break;
        case 'h':
        case '?':
        default:
            emit_help();
            /* NOTREACHED */
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    if (argc == 0)
        emit_help();

    if (!isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
        errx(1, "must have tty to read from");

    if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &terminfo) < 0)
        err(EX_OSERR, "could not tcgetattr() on stdin");

    Original_Termios = terminfo;

    // cfmakeraw(3) is a tad too raw and influences output from child;
    // per termios(5) use "Case B" for quick "any" key reads with
    // canonical mode (line-based processing) and echo turned off.
    terminfo.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    terminfo.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    terminfo.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &terminfo);
    atexit(reset_term);

    signal(SIGCHLD, child_signal);

    Child_Pid = fork();

    if (Child_Pid == 0) {       // child
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);
        status = execvp(*argv, argv);
        warn("could not exec '%s' (%d)", *argv, status);
        _exit(EX_OSERR);

    } else if (Child_Pid > 0) { // parent
        if ((status = read(STDIN_FILENO, &anykey, 1)) < 0)
            err(EX_IOERR, "read() failed??");
        kill(Child_Pid, SIGTERM);

    } else {
        err(EX_OSERR, "could not fork");
    }

    exit(Flag_UserOkay ? 0 : 1);
}

void child_signal(int unused)
{
    // might try to pass along the exit status of the child, but that's
    // extra work and complication...
    exit(0);
}

void emit_help(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: waitornot [-U] command [args ..]\n");
    exit(EX_USAGE);
}

void reset_term(void)
{
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &Original_Termios);
}
```